# Is there any free library in .Net support deleting entire excel column?

Tags: excel, npoi

I would like to find a library which support deleting entire column and row in excel. Unfortunately, EPPLUS and NPOI haven't supported this and their road maps haven't mentioned about this feature.

Currently, I set the width and height to zero, but it is not the best solution. Is there any free library in .Net support deleting entire excel column?

Answer (score 0):

reference the Microsoft Excel 10.0 Object Library in your project.

set the following using statement:

```
using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;
```

In your class, declare the following variables:

```
private Excel.Application _app;
private Excel.Workbooks _books;
private Excel.Workbook _book;
protected Excel.Sheets _sheets;
protected Excel.Worksheet _sheet;
```

then open the workbook in the following method:

```
protected void OpenExcelWorkbook(string fileName) 
{
_app = new Excel.Application();

if (_book == null) 
{
_books = _app.Workbooks;
_book = _books.Open(fileName, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing);
_sheets = _book.Worksheets;
}
}
```

Make sure you have a method that will close the workbook

```
protected void CloseExcelWorkbook() {
_book.Save();
_book.Close(false, Type.Missing, Type.Missing);
}
```

and you need a method to clean up references to Excel objects (since they are COM), otherwise Excel will remain running.

```
protected void NAR(object o) {

try {
if(o != null)
System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(o);
}

finally {
o = null;
}
}
```

Now you can select the worksheet you want to remove a row on:

```
OpenExcelWorkbook(@"d:\temp\yourworkbook.xls");
_sheet = (Excel.Worksheet)_sheets[1];
_sheet.Select(Type.Missing);
Excel.Range range = _sheet.get_Range("A7:A7", Type.Missing);
range.Delete(Excel.XlDeleteShiftDirection.xlShiftUp);
NAR(range);
NAR(_sheet);
CloseExcelWorkbook();
NAR(_book);
_app.Quit();
NAR(_app);
```